# Mongoose populate model nested in object

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to populate a model within an object. The parent model looks like:

```
{
  name: 'Test',
  Object: {'MR': {0: Model}}
}
```

I want to autopopulate 'Model' using the populate function of mongoose or a plugin, without using any loops. Is there any possibility?

Regards Sven

Comment: You can try using aggregation [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: Please add more details and the related mongoose schema